# Can somone help to write test-case for successful component destruction in StencilJs?

Tags: stenciljs

I am writing Unit test cases for SentcilJs Component.

```
  it('render component-name component', async () => {
    const page = await newSpecPage({
      components: [componentName],
      html: `<component-name model-id="${Model.id}"></component-name>`,
    });
    page.rootInstance.Data = {
      Model: [Model],
      Value: [Value],
      Status: []
    }
    page.rootInstance.tableModel = tableModel;
    page.rootInstance.tableValues = tableValues;
    await page.waitForChanges();
    const chart = page.root.shadowRoot.querySelector('component-html');
    expect(chart.innerHTML).not.toBeNull();
  });
```

this one is for successful render of components.

I would like to have test-case successful component destruction.

can someone help here?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with the component destruction? When it's been removed from the DOM?

Comment: I mean, destroy the component and test if it has been removed from UI.
Need Unit test case for the above scene.

Comment: Then just remove the component from the DOM and check whether it is present there. If not, you are good.

Comment: i was seeking/looking for some method to destroy component but looks like there is no method. i need to delete element only from HTML node. i agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

I tried calling the the `disconnectedCallback` directly from the test and expected the mocked methods to have been called.

```
    service.cleanup = jest.fn();
    page.rootInstance.disconnectedCallback();
    expect(service.cleanup).toHaveBeenCalled();
```